# How to bind an item name in the inner collection in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I have structure like

CollectionA
{
 ItemA
{
   Name 
}
}

I need to bind the collection's first item's Name property to a TextBox control.

I have this collection in my view model. How do i specify the collection's first element to a TextBox control in wpf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CollectionA[0].Name}"></TextBox>
```